# Как реализовать поиск от и до?

Tags: python, django

Хочу добавить в приложение возможность поиска по дате от и до. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форму StockHistorySearchForm создал для получения времени[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Во вьюшке функция showresults кажется мне совсем кривой, но не понимаю, как это связать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как правильно записать в templates так и не понял. Пару раз получалось реализовать поля для получения даты, но тогда исчезал поиск по имени.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот еще модели, на всякий [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, куда двигаться

Comment: неужели так сложно нажать Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V чтобы вставить код?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего поиск и фильтры реализовывать на фронте, с помощью JS это довольно просто делается. Если все же хочется на серверной стороне, то пожалуйста. Во-первых, создавать форму нужно используя подкласс Form, а не ModelForm:

```
from django import forms  

class Search(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(...)
```

Форму объявляем с методом GET в Template. Во views Вам нужно искать GET параметр с именем поля формы, если брать пример выше, это query, например:

```
def view(request):
...
if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.GET.get('query'):
        result = Model.objects.filter(...)
```

А дальше, на основании этого параметра можно фильтровать или наоборот исключать, как пожелаете. Этот result пихаем в контекст, вместо прошлого QuerySet, тем самым будут выведены только нужные объекты.